# How to change spacing between lines in Typst template?

Tags: typst

I'm creating a template for course paper. I need to write author's data like this:
[image]

But the result I was able to achieve is here:

[image]

So here is a code for it:

```
set text(size: 14pt)
  // Author information.
  align(
    right,
    pad(
      top: 1em,
    )[
     #underline("Работу выполнил:")
     
     #authormeta
    ]
  )
```

I need to reduce the line spacing, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried using grid and par, but nothing works, how do I do it?

(authormeta has "content" type and sequence of lines separated by parbreak())

Answer (score 4):

If the lines are separated by `parbreack()`, you can adjust the [`spacing`](https://typst.app/docs/reference/model/block/#parameters-spacing) between them.

```
#show par: set block(spacing: 0.65em)
```

To modify the spaces between the lines of a paragraph you can modify their [`leading`](https://typst.app/docs/reference/model/par/#parameters-leading) instead.